# "~/.bashrc: Permission denied" when opening mate-terminal

Tags: gnome-terminal, ubuntu-mate, bashrc

When I open a terminal, with my Ubuntu 18 with mate desktop is `mate-terminal` (probably like gnome-terminal for mate desktop) appears this message

`-bash: /home/albert/.bashrc: Permission denied`

and my .bashrc is not executed/loaded

I'm almost 100% sure than this file never has been executable, ant nor is now, but If I change their permisions to make it executable,then tries do exectute these first lines:

```
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac
```

and complains in `return` says something that is not a function ...this code must be sourced...

---

Edited:

If I use UXTerm, it seems that .bashrc is exectued successfully, but something is missing, because I can not use rvm...I've lost the path
Any idea how to solve this?

```
ls -al $(which sh)
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Mar 25  2019 /bin/sh -> dash
```

It seems I'm using dash (not bash), may be this the problem? how can I change to bash? if so

Thank you very much

Comment: You may want to check the permissions of the file, which should be 644 or `-rw-r--r--`, and also owned by albert.

Comment: At first reset permissions to default with `chmod 644 ~/.profile ~/.bashrc`. Then please compare your `.bashrc` file with pre-installed default file from `/etc/skel`. You can use MeldMerge tool for visual comparison: `sudo apt install meld`, `meld ~/.bashrc /etc/skel/.bashrc`. My Ubuntu MATE 18.04 LTS  reports that they are equal. Did you changed `~/.profile`? If unsure - check it with `meld ~/.profile /etc/skel/.profile`. Please add output of `ls -al $(which sh)` to the question.

Comment: Thanks to both, I've checked and permisions are ok and there is no differences with the pre-installed default file

Comment: If I use UXTerm, it seems than .bashrc is exectued successfully --> edited in question

Comment: Are you using Dash or Bash? Please add output of `ls -al $(which sh)` to the question.

Comment: I'm using dash ...¿?¿?

Comment: `albert@albert-nuc:~$ ls -al $(which sh)` 
`lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Mar 25  2019 /bin/sh -> dash`

Comment: is this the problem...¿?

Comment: Using Dash is absolutely normal, it is default shell.

Comment: It is normal this message I get? so... how can I change to bash?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100654/discussion-between-n0rbert-and-albert-catala).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

During chat session we have located a typo in `~/.profile` file.

The problematic code block:

```
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
        "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi
```

should be changed to

```
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
        . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi
```

Note the dot (`.`) in the `"$HOME/.bashrc"` line above, it means sourcing.